# How to extract and merge the coordinates using Python?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, extract

Below is location information of 3 sequences: Sequence name, start site and end site. I would like to address the exact location of the sites. For example the value 785 is actually mean that the start site start to count from the location 27860291 and end with 789 which is 27861079 in actual. Can anyone help me?

**Code**

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from collections import defaultdict
output_file = open('B.bed','w')
with open('A.bed') as f:
    for line in f:
        name, start, stop = line.split()
        start =  int((name.split(':')[1].split('-')[0]))+line.index(start)
        stop = start + len(stop)            
        # print short_sequence_record.id, start, stop
    output_line ='%s\t%i\t%i\n' % \
        ((line.split(':')[0]),start,stop)
    output_file.write(output_line )
output_file.close()
```

**A.bed**

```
chr1:27860291-27862300  785 789
chr1:27860291-27862300  1539 1543
chr1:15504072-15506081  675 679
```

**Output**

```
chr1 15504096 15504099
```

**Expected output**

```
chr1 27861075 27861079
chr1 27861829 27861833
chr1 15504746 15504750
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your expected output, it would appear that you simply add the last 2 numbers of each line to the first number and subtract one.

```
import re  # regular expressions, not needed (alternatives: the `split` method) but convenient

re_pattern = r'[^:]*:(\d+)\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)'
with open(inputfile) as fin:
    for line in fin:
        start, _, offset_start, offset_end = re.search(re_pattern, line).groups()
        print('chr1 {} {}'.format(int(start) + int(offset_start) - 1,int(start) + int(offset_end) - 1))
```

There are several reasons why your code does not produce the desired output, one of which is that you're taking the length of a string with the code `stop = start + len(stop)`. You need to cast explicitly to int first. You also need to be mindful of your indentation: right now, you're only writing a *single* string *after* the for-loop has finished. You seem to want to do it during every run through that loop however.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can split the string to create a list as given below to do this:

```
ch = '27860291-27862300  785 789'
ll = [int(i) for i in re.split(r'[ -]+',ch)]
print ll
[27860291, 27862300, 785, 789]
start = ll[0]+ll[2]-1
end = ll[0]+ll[3]-1
print start,end
27861075 27861079
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an indentation error due to Python's use of significant whitespace. Because the output line is at the wrong indent level, Python thinks it should be executed outside the loop.

Here is the updated program:

```
from collections import defaultdict
output_file = open('B.bed','w')
with open('A.bed') as f:
    for line in f:
        name, start, stop = line.split()
        start =  int((name.split(':')[1].split('-')[0]))+line.index(start)
        stop = start + len(stop)            
        # print short_sequence_record.id, start, stop
        output_line ='%s\t%i\t%i\n' % \
        ((line.split(':')[0]),start,stop)
        output_file.write(output_line )
output_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is insufficient indentation of the `output_line ='%s\t%i\t%i\n' % ((line.split(':')[0]),start,stop)` line and the subsequent line.

```
from Bio import SeqIO

output_file = open('B.bed','w')
with open('A.bed') as f:
    for line in f:
        name, start, stop = line.split()
        start =  int((name.split(':')[1].split('-')[0])) + line.index(start)
        stop = start + len(stop)            

        # print short_sequence_record.id, start, stop
        output_line ='%s\t%i\t%i\n' % ((line.split(':')[0]), start, stop)
        print output_line
        output_file.write(output_line)

output_file.close()
```

Seems to generate the correct output, printing

```
chr1    27860315    27860318

chr1    27860315    27860319

chr1    15504096    15504099
```

This data landed in the file as can be be checked below:

```
with open('B.bed') as f:
    for line in f:
        print line,
```

which yields

```
chr1    27860315    27860318
chr1    27860315    27860319
chr1    15504096    15504099
```